# can some one help me with this statement

Tags: logic

True or False
$\forall \ x>0, \exists$ natural number $M$ such that $\forall \ $ natural numbers $n>M$, $0<$$ 1\over n $< $x$

I don't understand this statement so I don't know if it's true or false can some one explain.

I know that the statement says  for all $x>0$, there exists a natural number $m$, such that all natural numbers $n>M$, $0< {1 \over n}<x$

Comment: Start with an example, say $x=0.56$, now take $M=2$, now ask yourself can we say $0.56>1/n$ for all $n>2$? Then try for different $x$ and see if you can find such an $M$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you agree that, since $x>0$, there is a natural number $M$ such that$$0<\frac1M<x.$$But then what happens if $n\in\mathbb N$ is such that $n>M$? What happens is that$$0<\frac1n<\frac1M.$$And, since $\frac1M<x$, you know that$$0<\frac1n<x.$$I hope that this helps.

Comment: sure, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

$$n>M$$ implies $$0<\frac1n<\frac1M.$$

Then you need to achieve

$$0<\frac1n<x.$$

Obviously, $M$ such that $\dfrac1M<x$ will do because then

$$0<\frac1n<\frac1M<x.$$

The final question is: "can we find $M$ sucht that $\dfrac1M<x$ ?" and a possible value is

$$M=\left\lceil\frac1x\right\rceil,$$ which is defined for all $x>0$.

Comment: That's a really good explanation, thank you